# NLog can't write log file to disk

Tags: c#, nlog

Good day,
I am faced with problem. I try NLog, configuration code is listed below

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

fileTarget.FileName = @"D:\" + filename;
fileTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${logger} ${message}";

var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

LogManager.Configuration = config;

Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
logger.Debug("debug log message");
```

Code was taken from some tutorial. And nothing happened. Log file was not created on disk D. But it was created in project's output directory. I've tried `@"C:\" + filename`. I was surprised, but log file was there.

Then I've tried to log to `@"D:\SomeFolder\" + filename` and file also was there.

So, can anybody help me to understand what is wrong with `@"D:\" + filename`.

P.S. Visual Studio 2013, runned with Administrator's rights. Also, I've tried `${basedir}`. All was Ok.

Comment: Did you try searching? In 99.999% of cases this is a permissions issue, yet you mention nothing about the context (is this a desktop application or a web application) nor the permissions. In general, a disk's root directory is pretty restrictive with its permissions. See also [Logging Troubleshooting · NLog/NLog Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting), the first Google hit for "nlog not writing file".

Comment: @CodeCaster, hello. I do try searching. Also I've checked permissions. Maybe, I've missed something. I'll check again. This is desktop application. Disk C is system disk, so i was cunfused, that D is have less permissions.

Comment: When working with paths, use Path.Combine() to construct the paths, not the plus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the internal logging of NLog. Check what you have there. Also instead of writing the [internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging) to file write it to console.

```
 // enable internal logging to the console
    InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
```

Look for errors in the internal logs. You'll get the idea why it's not working.

Comment: thank you for response. Your answer was helpful, thanks. I didn't find any exception but I notice, NLog "eat" '\' symbol. Some logs look like 'D:\file.txt', and another 'D:file.txt'. I changed to 'D:\\file.txt' and all worked.

Comment: This bug will be fixed in NLog 4.3 (rc3) https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1350